# Mostrar datos de dos tablas mysql en php

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero mostrar datos de **dos tablas de una misma base de datos** en una misma página PHP.

Una tabla se llama "dpartidos" y la otra se llama "dpartidos2".

Ahora bien, quiero mostrar un dato que se llama "partido3" que está en "dpartidos2"

Mi código:

```html
$sql="SELECT * from dpartidos ";
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

if ($quediaes=="Wed" && 0 <= $hora && $hora <= 10) {
echo '<h3>No hay ningun partido en este momento</h3>';
}
else if ($quediaes=="Wed" && 11 <= $hora && $hora <= 12) {
  echo '<h3>Estás mirando: ' . $mostrar['partido1'] . '</h3>';
}

else if ($quediaes=="Wed" && 13 <= $hora && $hora <= 14) {
  echo '<h3>A continuacion: ' . $mostrar['partido3'] . '</h3>';
}
else if ($quediaes=="Wed" && 15 <= $hora && $hora <= 17 ) {
  echo '<h3>Estás mirando: ' . $mostrar['partido3'] . '</h3>';
}
else if ($quediaes=="Wed" && 16 <= $hora && $hora <= 23) {
echo '<h3>No hay ningun partido en este momento</h3>';
}
}
```

Comment: El concepto de base de datos no es tal como lo conoces en mysql, mas bien se deberia referir a ellas como `esquemas` si dentro del mismo server tienes 2 "base de datos" si quieres acceder a la tabla clientes le dices `SELECT nombre FROM base_datos1.clientes;` ahora consultas de otra "base de datos" clientes  `SELECT nombre FROM base_datos2.clientes`;

Comment: Me equivoqué, me refiero a una misma base de datos y mostrar datos de dos tablas distintas de esa misma base.

Comment: Amigo @MatiPHP, por favor te pido que seas un poco más cordial en la forma de preguntar, las personas que ofrecen sus respuestas ofrecen su tiempo y conocimiento para colaborar con la comunidad. Por favor, valóralos! Saludos y suerte :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si necesitas datos de distintas tablas puedes traerte los datos de ambas en diferentes variables mediante una query independiente para cada una.

```
// Este es tu primer set de datos que trae dpartidos
$sql_dbpartidos = "SELECT * from dpartidos";
$result_dbpartidos = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_dbpartidos);
$rows_dbpartidos = mysqli_fetch_array($result_dbpartidos);

// Este es tu segundo set de datos que trae dpartidos2
$sql_dbpartidos2 = "SELECT * from dpartidos2";
$result_dbpartidos2 = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_dbpartidos2);
$rows_dbpartidos2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_dbpartidos2);

if($rows_dbpartidos){

    if ($quediaes=="Wed" && 0 <= $hora && $hora <= 10) {
        echo '<h3>No hay ningun partido en este momento</h3>';
    }
    else if ($quediaes=="Wed" && 11 <= $hora && $hora <= 12) {
        echo '<h3>Estás mirando: ' . $rows_dbpartidos['partido1'] . '</h3>';
    }
    else if ($quediaes=="Wed" && 13 <= $hora && $hora <= 14) {
        if($rows_dbpartidos2){
            echo '<h3>A continuacion: ' . $rows_dbpartidos2['partido3'] . '</h3>';
        }
    }
    else if ($quediaes=="Wed" && 15 <= $hora && $hora <= 17 ) {
        if($rows_dbpartidos2){
            echo '<h3>Estás mirando: ' . $rows_dbpartidos2['partido3'] . '</h3>';
        }
    }
    else if ($quediaes=="Wed" && 16 <= $hora && $hora <= 23) {
        echo '<h3>No hay ningun partido en este momento</h3>';
    }

}
```

O en todo caso puedes hacer un [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) el cual en una sola consulta te permite unir los datos de distintas tablas relacionadas.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la ayuda. Me da un problema, es que me imprime miles de "No hay ningun partdio en este momento" tantos que se me crasheo la web.

Comment: Es por el while,  siempre va a hacer esas acciones porque siempre tendrás datos

Comment: Editar{e mi respuesta corrigiendo eso, cambiando el while por un if

Comment: Gracias, eso funcionó, ahora lo voy a estudiar bien, pero por que cambiaste el while por un if?

Comment: porque el while ejecuta todo lo que este dentro de el mientras la condicion que le has puesto sea verdadera, y no se detendrá nunca hasta que esa condición sea falsa, en cambio el if solo hace la validacion una vez. En tu caso solo necesitas validar una vez si estas trayendo datos o no.

Answer (score 1):

Debes realizar otra consulta a base de datos, ya que la que tienes solo te trae los datos de dpartidos. Deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
 $sql2="SELECT * from dpartidos2";
$result2=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

y cuando quieras llamar a la segunda tabla usas esa variable result2.

Comment: Lo puse así y no funciona: _while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
if ($quediaes=="Wed" && 13 <= $hora && $hora <= 21) {
  echo '<h3>A continuacion: ' . $mostrar['partido3'] . '</h3>';
}_

Comment: Debes realizar un mysqli_fetch_array para cada consulta a la base de datos.